How can I assume covariance (rho) between two psychiatric disorders for multivariate meta-analysis
I want to do a multivariate meta-analysis, as I have several effect sizes per study. For example, I want to investigate the risk (Odds Ratio) of Conduct Disorder (CD) and Oppositional Defiance Disorder (ODD) on Substance Use Disorders (including e.g., alcohol use disorder [AUD] and drug use disorder [DUD]). For example,
Study A studied risk of ODD on AUD, risk of ODD on DUD, risk of ODD on AUD and risk of CD on DUD.
Study B studied risk of ODD/CD on AUD and risk of ODD/CD on DUD (so not two different measures for ODD and CD, but together as one)
Study C studied risk of ODD on AUD/DUD and risk of CD on AUD/DUD
With multivariate meta-analysis I can control for the correlated structure of the predictors (ODD and CD) and outcomes (substance use disorders), as it takes the nested structure into account. The problem is that I have to assume covariance between the constructs in order to correctly correct for the correlated structure. The individual studies do not report this covariance.
How can I assume an adequate covariance? There is literature on e.g. genetic correlations between ODD and CD, should I use this genetic correlation as the covariance?
Or is it valid to do multivariate meta-analysis without regarding the covariance matrix, as long as one uses robust variance estimation?

Not a duplicate but this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207581/how-to-calculate-pre-and-post-treatment-hedges-g-effect-size-to-use-in-meta-ana?rq=1 may help
