Performing within-group meta-analysis without access to correlation coefficient r values
The idea is to perform a meta-analysis of single arm studies of an intervention in which there is a baseline measurement and post intervention measurement of a continuous outcome variable. The outcome variable is always measured on the same scale and no studies involve a control group. Plan would be to calculate the mean gain.
The issue I am having is I understand that the calculation of the standard error of the effect size which I need to do the meta-analysis "requires" a correlation r value when dealing with within-group, pre-post intervention scenarios. These r values are never reported in the literature and would have to be estimated which seems very problematic. Do I have any options to perform the meta-analysis without the correlation r term?
All I have is mean, sd and n at time 1 pre intervention and mean, sd and n at time 2 post intervention.
Am working in R with metafor - am going down the "4a" pathway.

See this Q&A https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207581/how-to-calculate-pre-and-post-treatment-hedges-g-effect-size-to-use-in-meta-ana?rq=1
